# If $T$ is a topological isomorphism, then so is $T^*$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, adjoint-operators

The question comes from the following link on page 25:
https://www.ucl.ac.uk/~ucahad0/3103_handout_3.pdf

They prove $(T^{-1})^*=(T^*)^{-1}$, but I don't see how it proves $T^*$ is a topological isomorphism.

Comment: You need $T^*$ to have an inverse, and lo and behold, it's $(T^{-1})^*$.

Comment: We have that the adjoint is bounded and linear, hence continuous. The thing I'm not too certain about is where to get it to also be bijective.

Comment: the claimed identity proves that it is bijective.

Comment: I can't believe I forgot about this! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Randall, I was able to figure it out.

$T^*$ having an inverse implies it is bijective. We also know the adjoint is bounded and linear. We can use this to show $T^*$ is a topological isomorphism.